# Australian Passport processing Time

Tags: canada, australia, passport, australian-citizens

I went into the consulate the other day to apply for the renewal of my Australian passport as I was born there and haven't renewed it in the past year. I had all the documents in order and the application was approved. The Australian Passports Office website says that it only takes ten days to get a passport but they said at the consulate that it would take six weeks. Also, the online tracker doesn't seem to be working for me, I just keep getting an error page

Are there any other Aussies who could share with me their experience regarding passport waiting time?

Note: I live in Canada, the regional passport processing centre for Australia is in Washington.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my answer from where this was asked on [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/38516/101)

Brilliantly, they're not clear on the [embassy website for Aussies in Canada.](http://www.canada.embassy.gov.au/otwa/consular.html)  However, after some searching it comes down to two options.

1. The express service - priority processing fee applies, means that your urgent/emergency application can be [processed and ready for collection or dispatch](http://www.canada.embassy.gov.au/otwa/090321_Travel_Doc_Fees.html) within 48 hours.
2. The standard service - where it goes via mail through their center in Washington, DC, most likely, [takes 10 working days from receipt of all valid documents](https://www.passports.gov.au/Web/FAQ.aspx#faq4):

> We are equally committed to prompt processing of passport applications
>   made overseas at any Australian diplomatic or consular mission. In
>   most cases an eligible applicant's full validity passport will be
>   available for collection or despatch from the mission within ten
>   working days of a passport interview if all our requirements are met.
>   It will be issued by one of our passport production centres - London,
>   Washington, or Canberra. You should allow extra time for local mail
>   delivery if you have requested that the passport be mailed to you.

They also point out that if you need it sooner, you should resort to option 1.